# javascript closest element by selector return null

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following script to get the ancestor of an element

```
<form id="form1">
  <div id="div1">
    <label id="label1">some label</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="btn1">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

this script works fine, as in it returns the `form` element

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn1');
console.log(btn);
const form = btn.closest('form');
console.log('form', form); // this returns the <form> element
```

but when I added some script to append an element using `innerHTML`, the `form` variable contains null.

```
const iconLoading = '<i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>';
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn1');
console.log(btn);
const parent = btn.parentElement;
parent.innerHTML += iconLoading;
const form = btn.closest('form');
console.log('form', form); // this returns null
```

here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nu4tsx3/5/). what am I doing wrong? any help is appreciated

```js
const iconLoading = '<i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>';
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn1');
console.log(btn);
const parent = btn.parentElement;
parent.innerHTML += iconLoading;
const form = btn.closest('form');
console.log('form', form);
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <div id="asd1">
    <label id="label1">some label</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="btn1">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use the built in code tool to make a running example within the question.

Comment: I think using `innerHTML` caused the `btn` variable to reference a button that's no-longer on the page? `document.contains(btn)` is also false. -- Consider not using `innerHTML`

Comment: You'll need to call `document.querySelector('#btn1')` again using `closest()`.

Comment: Some advice, I would stay away from adding in HTML for a loading spinner, instead have that spinner always present, but hidden. Show and hide it as needed.

Comment: const form = document.querySelector('#btn1').closest('form'); how @0stone0 says you have to select the element again, for some reason your const btn is not longer in the page...

Comment: You should use `parent.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', iconLoading);`, it's prefered over `+= innerHTML` and fixes your problem.

Comment: Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead